# Can't connect to DC from workstation using File Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2016, network-share, windows-server-2022

Here's a small piece of my topology:

```
SERVER2   - ePDC           (SERVER 2016 Essentials)
SERVER3   - Peer DC        (SERVER 2022 Standard)
RECEPTION - Workstation    (Windows 10 21H2)
```

SERVER2 is down for a week, waiting on a part from Dell. In the meantime I'm on RECEPTION trying to browse to a share on SERVER3 so I can copy over some large files (USB2 only on that machine, so there's no hope of anything fast with that).

I'm getting this error on RECEPTION:

```
Windows cannot access \\SERVER3\Files
0x80070035
The network path was not found
```

or

```
Windows cannot access \\SERVER3\Files
0x00004005
Unspecified error
```

Things I've tried:

1. Turned off the firewall on SERVER3
2. Enabled SMB in Windows Features
3. Enabled Network Sharing/File Discovery on both SERVER3 and RECEPTION
4. Enabled and started all services mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/cannot-access-shared-folder-file-explorer)

I can ping SERVER3 from RECEPTION without any problem. This also occurs from other workstations in the LAN. For some reason I'm unable to get to SERVER3 via File Explorer.

What further do I need to do so that I can connect to SERVER3?

**---- EDIT 2022-09-29 ----**

I was able to bring SERVER2 (the PDCe) back online—the Dell parts are still on order, but it's in a VM and I was able to move it over to a temporary host—and suddenly the connectivity problem from the workstations to the DC peer SERVER3 abated.

I have no idea why this happened.

Comment: What does ```net view \\server3``` show?   Is there a DNS set up?

Comment: `System error 53, the network path was not found`. Yes, DNS is replicated between SERVER2 and SERVER3. (But, as mentioned, SERVER2 is down right now.)

Comment: Then is Reception pointing to the Sever3 DNS?

Comment: As its secondary DNS, yes. SERVER3 pings successfully from RECEPTION. Also, I can browse RECEPTION'S C$/D$ admin shares from SERVER3, but not the other way around.

Comment: Other workstations elicit these exact symptoms & successes, so the problem appears to be on SERVER3.

Comment: Time synchronized?  Is the network adapter set to the correct network profile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139500/discussion-between-intexx-and-ewokx).

Comment: I don't see anything about the status of the domain on SERVER3. These commands should be run on SERVER3:  `nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com` `netdom query fsmo`. Also I believe essentials holds the FSMO roles...which is obviously not compatible with being down for "weeks"

Comment: down for Weeks? a DC should not be longer as 30 days disconnected...?! and if you need to copy files, use an SATA Adapter for migration if needed.

Comment: @GregAskew — You are correct; WSE holds FSMO. I also was concerned about the long downtime; I moved SERVER2's VM onto a temporary host, started it up, and suddenly workstations were able to browse shares on the SERVER3 DC. Very strange.

Comment: @djdomi — Not weeks, just a week. Nevertheless, I agree; even one week is too long. Fortunately SERVER2 is in a VM, so I was able to bring it back online on a temporary host. Oddly, the problem went away as soon as I did that.

Comment: because the PDC seems to be server and maybe also the primary dns.

Comment: @djdomi — I considered the same thing, but since I was unable to browse to `\\192.168.2.13\Share` it must've been something else. Perhaps something in the security configuration that wouldn't let a workstation trust SERVER3 until the FSMO roles came back online. That's my best guess.

Comment: In a busy environment a PDCe offline can go downhill in a few hours. Also if the RID master isn't available and you run out of RID's, that's not good either.

Comment: @GregAskew — `if the RID master isn't available and you run out of RID's` [sic] That seems a likely culprit.